# Index on partitioned table: Naming of indexes on partitions

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, when I create an index on a partitioned table e.g. via

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON measurement (city_id,peaktemp);
```

Postgres creates an index on each partition of the table for me initially and when I add new partitions to the table. But I do not like the naming schema which seems to be

```
partition_name + index columns + literal 'idx'
```

Can I influence that naming schema? I would prefer

```
name of index on parent table + partition name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot influence the name PostgreSQL chooses, but it is simple to rename the indexes on the partitions afterwards.

If you attach a table as a new partition, there is another way: create the index with the name of your choice *before* you attach the partition, then PostgreSQL will automatically use that index as partition of the partitioned index.

Comment: thank you. I like the idea of renaming the index after creation.